# Form refresh after parse.com submission

Tags: javascript, html, forms, parse-platform

Here is the code for an html form I'm working on to submit information it is working as intended but the webpage keeps the input information in the form fields after submitting.

I've tried to use a couple on button press refreshes but it doesn't forward the data to the database at parse.com.

Does anyone know how to get the fields to reset/refresh after the form has submitted?

```
<div class="register span5 offset3">
            <form id="signupForm">
                <h2>Create an account <!--<span class="red"><strong>iAPP</strong></span>--></h2>
                <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="first name">
                <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="last name">
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="username">
                <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email address">
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="password">
                <button type="submit">SIGN UP</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        </div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    Parse.initialize("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx1");

    function signUp(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var firstname = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
        var lastname = document.getElementById("lastname").value;
        var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
        var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
        var email = document.getElementById("email").value;

        var user = new Parse.User();
        user.set("firstname", firstname);
        user.set("lastname", lastname);
        user.set("username", username);
        user.set("password", password);
        user.set("email", email);

        // other fields can be set just like with Parse.Object
        user.set("phone", "650-555-0000");

        user.signUp(null, {
                    success: function (username) {
                        // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
                    },
                    error: function (username, error) {
                        // Show the error message somewhere and let the user try again.
                        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
                    }

                }
        );
    }
    document.getElementById('signupForm').addEventListener('submit', signUp);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

- Add Reset Button Inside form field and reset all field without going to DB Connection .

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="register span5 offset3">
            <form id="signupForm">
                <h2>Create an account <!--<span 

class="red"><strong>iAPP</strong></span>--></h2>
                <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="first name">
                <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="last name">
                <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="username">
                <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email address">
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" 

placeholder="password">
                <button type="submit">SIGN UP</button>
      <button type="reset" value="Reset">Reset</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        </div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    Parse.initialize("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", 

"1xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx1");

    function signUp(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var firstname = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
        var lastname = document.getElementById("lastname").value;
        var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
        var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
        var email = document.getElementById("email").value;

        var user = new Parse.User();
        user.set("firstname", firstname);
        user.set("lastname", lastname);
        user.set("username", username);
        user.set("password", password);
        user.set("email", email);

        // other fields can be set just like with Parse.Object
        user.set("phone", "650-555-0000");

        user.signUp(null, {
                    success: function (username) {
                        // Hooray! Let them use the app now.
                    },
                    error: function (username, error) {
                        // Show the error message somewhere and let the user try again.
                        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
                    }

                }
        );
    }
    document.getElementById('signupForm').addEventListener('submit', signUp);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about inside of the success function on User Signup, just clear all the input fields in the form?

Example

```
success: function (username) {
                    document.getElementById("example").value = "";
                }
```

Or relocate them

Example

```
success: function (username) {
                    location.assign("http://www.mypage.com/myhomepage");
                }
```